# agregar jquery a mi pagina con angular-cli

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs-2.0, typescript

Necesito agregar jquery para inicializar componentes de semantic ui a mi  proyecto en angular-cli lo he descargado por npm y 
He agregado la ruta en el angular-cli.json pero a la hora de compilar me sale

```
$ is not defined
```

Comment: Necesitas agregar más información sobre como estás usando ese paquete, de modo que puedas recibir ayuda. Sigue esta guía __[mcve]__.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

en lo personal utilizo angular con bootstrap 4, yo he resuelto ese conflicto agregando una sola linea de código en el componente que necesito utilizar jQuery

```
declare var $:any;
@component({
    selector: 'app-home',
    .....
})
```

sobra decir que debes tener instalado jQuery en el proyecto.

Saludos :)

Answer (score 0):

Buenas,

Ayudaría que pongas codigo aqui, mas datos, capturas de pantalla....

De todas formas, aquí tienes los pasos para usar semantic ui para Angular, que es lo que te recomiendo que uses y no la librería normal:

> https://ng-semantic.herokuapp.com/#/

Answer (score 0):

[image: me sale este error no se que mas]

este es mi package.json

```js
{
  "name": "SaveBPM",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^4.0.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "jquery": "^3.2.1",
    "ng-semantic": "^1.1.13",
    "rxjs": "^5.1.0",
    "semantic-ui": "^2.2.10",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.38",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "~2.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.5.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~3.2.0",
    "karma": "~1.4.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^0.2.0",
    "protractor": "~5.1.0",
    "ts-node": "~2.0.0",
    "tslint": "~4.5.0",
    "typescript": "~2.2.0"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

sé que esta pregunta ya tiene tiempo pero igual voy a dar mi opinión.

Tomando en cuenta que:

1. Necesitas JQuery y no otro plugin.
2. Incluiste JQuery en el archivo angular-cli.json
3. Recibes este mensaje "$ is not defined"

Declarando la variable en TypeScript como indicó Gersom deberías poder resolver.

> declare var $:any;

Answer (score 0):

Yo uso angular6 y se me hizo un poco complicado usar jquery pero encontré algo que si capas usas angular 6 te pueda ayudar.

Instalas

```
npm install jquery --save
npm install @types/jquery --save
```

Esto es en el **package.json** solo para angular6

```
styles": [
    "styles.css",
  ],
  "scripts": [
    "./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
  ]
```

pero en versiones anteriores se usaba esto en el **package.json**

```
styles": [
    "styles.css",
  ],
  "scripts": [
    "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
  ]
```

Answer (score -1):

en app.module.ts
agrega

```
import * as $ from 'jquery';
(obviamnete incluyendo las libreriras en el archivo angular.json)
```